# Asterisk call flow

Tags: android, sip, asterisk, voip

I want to use asterisk server for SIP/VOIP calls from/to android app. I searched for good Sip client and found CSip simple is good.

Suppose there are 2 users A and B.

- when A wants to call to B,

  - A sends request to internal server
  - Internal server will check if A can call B or not by populating some database value
  - If yes, Server will ask B if it wants to accept call from A
  - If yes, server will setup call between A and B

How i should configure these things in asterisk to achieve this and also like to know that if CSipSimple will be best for android?

If i am wrong anywhere please correct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

CSipSimple will be best for android.

For asterisk i try to solve your problem. Try below configuration to make call.

Suppose there are 2 users A and B.

A user server

> Modified A server extension.conf

```
[my_outgoing]
//exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})  
exten => _X.,1,AGI(test.php)  
// test.php is check for balance of A and if A having enough balance then it will call B from this file it self
```

> Modified A server sip.conf

```
[2221]
username=2221
type=friend
secret=2221
host=dynamic
context=my_outgoing
```

> Modified B server extension.conf

```
[my_incoming]
//exten => _X.,1,Answer()
exten => _X.,1,AGI(test2.php)
// Here test2.php is for run IVR from script and give user for press 1 or 2 to accept and reject the call etc...  
// if you are using the real device or soft phone then it will handle the call option by it self  
// If you have to handle this using script then code to handle call written into this  
// And if GUI [from soft phone] is there to handle call then write bellow line only     

exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
```

> Modified B server sip.conf

```
[2222]
username=2222
type=friend
secret=2222
host=dynamic
context=default
```

Now try to register both user from different device and try to make call.
Call from A(2221) to B(2222)